# For $x>1$, prove that $x^p<x^q$ whenever $p<q$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

The statement: For $x>1$, prove that $x^p<x^q$ whenever $p<q$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Here is what I have attempted: $$q>p\Rightarrow q-p>0$$

Using this fact, we then exponentiate both sides by $x$.
$$x^{q-p}>x^0\Rightarrow x^{q-p}>1\Rightarrow x^q>x^p$$

Another attempt is $$q>p\Rightarrow\vert\frac{q}{p}\vert>1$$

Since $$x>1\Rightarrow x^{\vert q/p\vert}>1\Rightarrow x^{\vert q\vert}>x^{\vert p\vert}$$  Both of them are incorrect.

Yet another attempt:

Since $x>1$. This implies that for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a>0$ $$x^a\geq1\,\,...(1)$$
Must be true. Let $q-p>0$. Then by $(1)$, we have that $$x^{q-p}\geq1\\\\\because q-p>0$$

Hence, $$x^{q-p}\geq1\Rightarrow x^q\geq x^p$$
 I am wondering if there is a way to correct them...Also would the proof be any different if $q,p\in\mathbb{R}$ instead?

Quick sidenote: is the term exponentiate correct?

Comment: Where did you use $x>1$?

Comment: Or: $ln(x^p)<ln(x^q)\rightarrow pln(x)<qln(x)$, since $x>1$, $ln(x)>0$ hence $p<q$.

Comment: @JosephZambrano Thank you. Now I know that t is an if and only if statement. But I am trying to prove it the other direction.

Comment: I'm sorry I misread: let $p<q$ and $x>1$. Let $n,m,r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ (wlog $m,s>0$) such that $p=n/m$ and $q=r/s$. Now $p<q\rightarrow n/m<r/s\rightarrow ns<rm$ and $ns,rm\in\mathbb{Z}$. Possibly use an argument like this?

Comment: I do not understand why your first attempt is wrong, it seems right to me. Can you please explain why you think its wrong?

Moreover, $x$ does belong to what? $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @dadexix86 I didn't use the fact that $x>1$...that's why. I think I got it now.

Comment: You used it. In the implication $q-p>0 \Rightarrow x^{q-p}>x^0$. Indeed, this implication would be false otherwise. Let $q=3, p=2$. Then $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3-2}<\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^0$.

Comment: @dadexix86 Oh I see. So I just have to state that explicitly?

Comment: If you need to... But for me the first proof is ok as it is. And yes, it works for every $p, q \in \mathbb{R}$, this because $x^r$ (as a function that depends on $r$) is strictly increasing for every $r\in \mathbb{R}$ and every $x\in\mathbb{R}, x>1$. If you want to spend some time you can also think about what happens when $0<x<1$? And when $x=1$? And can we say something about $x<0$? Enjoy your time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma**: If $q\in \mathbb{Q}^{>0}$ and $x,y>0$, $x>y\iff x^q>y^q$

Proof: 
($\Rightarrow$) $q=a/b$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. So we have  $x^{1/b}> y^{1/b}$ (why? argue by contradiction) and then $x^q=(x^{1/b})^a> (y^{1/b})^a=y^q$

($\Leftarrow$) Conversely suppose that $x^q> y^q$ as $q=a/b$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, $x^a=(x^q)^b> (y^q)^b=y^a$, i.e., $x^a>y^a$ for $a\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. If were not the case $x>y$ we get a contradiction. $\square$

**Claim**: If $x>1$, $x^p<x^q\iff p<q$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose to the contrary that $p\ge q$. So, $p-q\ge 0$. Thus by the previous lemma   $x^{p-q}\ge1$ and since $x^q>0$ (why?), then $x^p\ge x^q$, a contradiction.

($\Leftarrow$) We have  $q-p>0$. Thus $x^{q-p}>1$ and since $x^p>0$, we're done.

For the real case what is your definition of real exponentiation?